# users can't access our web content before they are logged in

Tags: php, sql-server

Till now I working in my website. The user on this website must log in before they can access the content. But I have a problem to make user session in PHP. I using sql server as my database.
Let check it out.

code of log in page

```
<form name="login" action="cek_login.php" method="POST" onSubmit="return validasi()">
<div class=log>My Id</div><div class=log><input type="text" name="username"></div>
<div class=log>Password</div><div class=log><input type="password"  name="sandi"></div>
<div class=log><input id="tombol" type="submit" value="Login" ></div>
</form>
```

my cek_login.php code

```
<?php
session_start();
include "config/koneksi.php";

$login=mssql_query("SELECT * FROM tblMstUser
                    WHERE LoginID='$_POST[username]' 
                    AND PasswordPHP='$_POST[sandi]'"); 

$ketemu=mssql_num_rows($login);
$r=mssql_fetch_array($login);

// Apabila username dan password ditemukan
if ($ketemu > 0){   
    session_register("LoginID");
    session_register("PasswordPHP");


  $_SESSION[LoginID]  = $r[LoginID];
  $_SESSION[PasswordPHP] = $r[PasswordPHP];

 header('location:home.php');
}
else{
  echo "<link href=../config/adminstyle.css rel=stylesheet type=text/css>";
  echo "<center><strong>LOGIN GAGAL!</strong> <br> 
        Username atau Password Anda tidak benar.<br>
        Atau account Anda Tidak Punya Hak Akses Untuk Halaman ini.<br>";
  echo "<a href=index.php><b>ULANGI LAGI</b></a></center>";
}
?>
```

my home page code

```
<?php
include('config/koneksi.php');//connect to database
include('cek-login.php');//session user to make autorithy that user cann't acces this before loged-in
?>
<div id="menu" style="height:190px;width:115px;float:left;">
<b>Menu</b><br>
<br>&nbsp;</br>
<li><a href="BudgetAprovalByTop_List/view.php">Budget Aproval<br></li>
<li><a href="PPBAprovalByTop_List/view.php">PPB Aproval</a><br></li>
<li><a href="logout.php">LOG OUT</a></li>
</div>
```

Code of cek-login.php

```
session_start();

//if session doesn't make, or session username is empty
if (!isset($_SESSION['username']) || empty($_SESSION['username'])) {
    //redirect to login page
    header('location:index.php');
}
?>
```

After user log in and succes but the user can't access the home page. C'z in my session code above(cek-login.php) read empty username or doesn't make so redirect to log in page again

Comment: sorry, no idea what you are asking

Comment: couple of things to improve: http://chat.stackoverflow.com/transcript/message/8194758#8194758

Answer (score 0):

session_register() = This function has been DEPRECATED as of PHP 5.3.0 and REMOVED as of PHP 5.4.0.

Try the following...

```
$_SESSION['LoginID']  = $r['LoginID'];
$_SESSION['PasswordPHP'] = $r['PasswordPHP'];
```